# CSS Sprite hover state from parent element

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs

I am using CSS sprites to show an icon on a sort up/down button. These sprites are generated by external software on each build, a simple CSS-only solution wouldn't work, so I want to add a custom class via Angular.

```
<a href ng-click="sortToggle()">
    <span class="sprite" ng-class="{ sort_up: direction, sort_down: !direction }"></span>
    Sort
</a>
```

Where the class is toggled on each click of the `<a>` link. Now I have a requirement to be able to hover on the `<a>` element and append `_hover` onto the `.sprite` class list, so I wrote this directive:

```
app.directive("sortHover", [
    function() {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            link: function ($scope, element) {
                var $sprite = element.find("span.sprite");
                element.hover(function() {
                    // How do I modify ng-class here?
                    var obj = $sprite["ng-class"]; // Example
                    // Hopefully add my hover state something like this
                    if(obj.sort_up) {
                        obj.sort_up = false;
                        obj.sort_up_hover = true;
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Which would be used like:

```
<a href sort-hover ng-click="sortToggle()"> .... </a>
```

But I am unsure of how to modify the `ng-class` object here. The directive could be added to `.sprite` instead if that helps?

Any ideas? I'm using full jQuery & Angular 1.2.11, but don't mind upgrading if that's required.

Comment: You want to switch arrow on hover the <a> element ?

Comment: I am not sure but this has to be like this: `var $sprite = angular.element(element).find("span.sprite");`.

Comment: @Bluety Need to change the class on the `<span>` element, but on hover of the `<a>` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question well, you can make it only with CSS like so:

```
.sort_up,
a:hover .sprite.sort_down {
    // your CSS
}

.sort_down,
a:hover .sprite.sort_up {
    // your CSS
}
```

Try to replace your code by:

```
element.on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
    $scope.direction = !$scope.direction;
});
```

Comment: I should have specified, but `// Your CSS` is being generated by an external software and changes on each build.